# Why are the Russian Federation's Strategic Rocket Forces and the 12th Chief Directorate separate?

Tags: military, russia, nuclear-weapons

It seems that:

- the [Strategic Rocket Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Rocket_Forces) (РВСН РФ) is the branch of the [Russian Armed Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Armed_Forces) (ВС РФ) tasked with the employment of nuclear weapons.
- the [12th Chief Directorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12th_Chief_Directorate) of the [Ministry of Defense of the Russian Federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Defence_(Russia)) (МО РФ) is tasked with the maintenance and protection of nuclear weapons, and are usually touted as being even more secretive than the former.

Though I can see there being differences between maintenance and employment of nuclear weapons, I just see so much overlap between the two. Wouldn't it make more sense to have just one single organization?

Also, why is the organization tasked with maintaining the weapons more secretive than the one tasked with actually using them?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have much of a historical aspect to it. Current Russian military organisation _might_ have its origins in the Soviet Union but why it's as it is right now is probably off-topic on this site.

Comment: Your first and last paragraph conflict in which one of the two organizations is touted as "more secred". Also, maintining / protecting nuclear weapons is nuclear physics and maintenance of warheads. Deployment is (literally) rocket physics. The deliverance system has nothing to do with the payload, really. Oversimplified, the SRF get the payload to the target and then close some circuit. Whether it's a nuke that goes boom or some chemical explosive, they couldn't care less.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I modified the order of the bullet points to suit what I meant

Comment: Agreeing with @SteveBird. One good way to tell that a question **is not a history question** is if none of the verbs used in the question sentences are past tense. There isn't even a single past-tense verb in this entire question.

Comment: @T.E.D. I think checking the accepted answer will provide ample justification...

Comment: Distantly related: [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/58651/17887) and [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/59551/17887)

Comment: Why *was* it separated is a history question. Why they don't change that today (which this question seems to be asking) is not. Danila gave us a historical answer to a non-historical question (good for them!). Perhaps you'd like this question edited to make it more on topic (and incidentally make the accepted answer more directly answering what it asks)? I agree with @RodrigodeAzevedo that it doesn't look like it would be tough to do.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo As a Russian speaker, I understand this to mean "after the bombs fall, there is silence", not as an indication of their secretiveness, though the nuance is subtle and I might be wrong

Comment: @T.E.D. My intent was definitely not to ask why they don't change it today, but why it is like this in the first place. As many things that are true of the military today (most!), I assumed there would be a historical explanation to this, not a purely logical one with both being simultaneously created ex nihilo.

Comment: You may want to read [Strategic Missile Troops](https://nuke.fas.org/guide/russia/agency/rvsn.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

12th Chief Directorate originated from the Main Directorate of special weaponry of USSR MoD. This organisation was created in 1947 to coordinate R&D, production and storage of nuclear weapons and to develop guidelines on their usage (and on defensive measures against similar enemy weapons). As a result, by 1951, when training started for actual military personnel who would be using the nukes (the Soviet Air Force), the Main Directorate of special weaponry already had a sizeable infrastructure dedicated to transport, storage and maintenance of the weapons - note that these storage sites were also responsible for the final assembly of nukes.

In addition to storage bases, in their R&D capacity, the Main Directorate was responsible for operating the testing grounds and nuclear detonation detection facilities. When SORT treaties were made, they also were charged with operating  decommissioning facilites, too. They are still responsible for long-range nuclear detonation detection laboratories (and control over international treaties implementation, but I guess these guys don't have too much work on their hands these days).

This gave the organisation a very particular skillset. They basically control the most of Russian nuclear weapons' lifecycle (which is why they are so secretive); RVSN (and other potential users) only receive fully ready warheads, they are responsible for putting them on delivery systems and priming, but nothing else - they used to have some storage bases, giving them that overlap you mentioned, but these were transferred to the 12th Directorate when it was formed.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: A comprehensive answer, but sources would improve it